# navigator.notification.beep doesn't play sound ios

Tags: ios, cordova, notifications, beep

I'm using the notification plugin to play a beep on my iOS app but the sound doesn't play. Here's the example code when I click a button:

```
navigator.notification.beep(1);
navigator.notification.alert("Hello");
```

The alert is shown correctly but the sound doesn't play. I get no errors in console, i'm using cordova ios@4.3.1

Comment: is the sound on?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yes the sound is on